# why my code does not run on drush?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, drush

The following code when i run it out of the drush command all goes fine... But when i want to create a drush command nothing works :/

```
/**
 * Implements drush_hook_my_command().
 */
function drush_my_module_create_driver_licence_term() {
$licence = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('driver_licence');
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($licence->vid);

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', $term->tid);
    $wrapper->field_blablabla->set(4453);
    $wrapper->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: "nothing works" how? Command is not recognized? Is recognized but function does not fire? Fire, but shows error? Fire, no error, but field is not set? Something else?

Comment: it runs without errors but using drush_logs i can see that it do not get in foreach :/ Could i see somehow if drush finds out some values in $terms variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more luck starting off with a working example Drush command.  See the [drushify](https://www.drupal.org/project/drushify) project for a code generator that will create one for you.  From there, if you do not want to set up a source level debugger, you can always add [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/7.0.0/includes/drush.inc#L1246)_log calls to print out the values of your variables.